# Possible to update within iOS 6?

Tags: iphone, upgrade, software-update, ios

If I purchase a brand new iPhone 5 and it has iOS 6.0, can I still upgrade to 6.1.4? I do **NOT** want iOS 7 or 8.

Comment: Do you have a reason to suspect that the iPhone will be running iOS 6? I think I've heard that they update phones in inventory.

Comment: It is in the shrink-wrapped sealed box with the picture of an iPhone with iOS 6 on it... hmm now I'm worried.

Comment: I have heard that they are able to push updates to the phones even in the box, but again, perhaps that is rumor.

Comment: Is there any way to tell without opening the box? That is ridiculous. How can a powered off phone receive and apply an update? I'm scared XD

Comment: You might be able to check the serial number online in order to get the manufacture date.  I think the serial number is printed on the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the phone is capable of running iOS 8, then there would be no chance to upgrade to any other older version. Updates must be validated (signed) by Apple at the time they are applied and Apple has stopped signing iOS 6 and iOS 7 updates for all but a very few devices which cannot run iOS 8.